# Overriding Block in Magento 2

Tags: blocks, overrides, php-5.4, magento2-dev-beta

I'm playing overriding the blocks in magento 2, extended block constructor is calling but inside method is not working?

**my code is**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" type="Learning\Customers\Block\Info" />
</config>
```

**Info.php**

```
  <?php

namespace Learning\Customers\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Info extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\View $helperView,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/Info.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($this->getName());

        parent::__construct($context,$currentCustomer,$subscriberFactory,$helperView, $data);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Magento 2';
    }

}
```

**Any suggestions?**

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? what happens when you try it?

Comment: @Marius, `constructor()` is calling, but `getName()` method is not overriding i.e., not displaying **Magento 2**

Comment: @Marius any help on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add below method to `Info.php`

```
protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info'));
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
```

see reference Link [How to Overriding block in Magento 2](http://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Overriding-a-block-in-Magento-2/m-p/6831#U6831)

Answer (score 0):

Overriding Block is done but issue is when i get current category id using registry in magento 2 showing error

There has been an error processing your request.
Object DOMDocument should be created

Any one know how can i get current category id in Toolbar block.