# Overriding Sales\Block\Order\View Block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, overrides, custom-block, preference

I am trying to extend `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View` by using preferences to get some more information into customer order view page.
Everything works fine if i remove __construct. so what might be the root cause of this issue?

Have been following lot of answers from community but no luck.  ( removed cache,generation and done upgrade ) [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76590/overriding-block-in-magento-2)

**Errors :**

From report : Object DOMDocument should be created.

From log    :

> Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Magento\Framework\Registry,

```
namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Block\Order;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
/**
 * Sales order view block
 */
class View extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View
{

    // Some protected properties 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context,$paymentHelper,$registry,$httpContext, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that the payment helper you inject via dependency injection is not at the right position of the original constructor.

To fix that you need to replace:

```
parent::__construct($context,$paymentHelper,$registry,$httpContext, $data);
```

With:

```
parent::__construct($context,$registry,$httpContext, $paymentHelper, $data);
```

Comment: Thanks for response , now am getting Argument 4 passed to Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Payment\Helper\Data.

Comment: @krishnaijjada see my edit. By the way if you don't inject extra dependencies you don't need to add the constructor to your code ;)

Comment: Perfect..:)  It is working as charm. so the passing variables in the Constructor is important. in which order do i have to follow for inserting new dependencies. do i need to send to parent constructor? what is the core hack for this type of errors ?

Comment: @krishnaijjada feel free to ask a new question and send it to me as it'll be hard to answer as a comment ;)