# get store categories inside phtml file magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to customize `topmenu.phtml` file but I see, I can customize limited html. How I can create my own menu and get store categories inside phtml?

Comment: What do you mean by "can customize limited html" ?

Comment: for example in topmenu.html we don't have access to <li>. I have to add classes to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options for this, depending on your requirements for customization, you can:

1. Create a plugin that would listen on `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml` event. If you want to add items to the menu, you would listen for `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` event and add items to the `menu` parameter. Otherwise, if you want to edit the direct HTML you can listen for `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after` which returns the HTML and you can edit it before passing it to the template.
2. Second option is to override the `/vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php` block and the `/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml` template for your customizations.

For information on how to do these, take a look at [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) on how to use plugins or [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76590/overriding-block-in-magento-2) on how to override the block.

I would normally recommend going for plugins instead of override, but if you want to create a completely new topmenu you should go for the override.

Comment: If i create a module and override block, it won't be part of my theme anymore? Is this recommended way? For example If I move my theme in future, I will need to copy modules with it as well?

Comment: Correct, if you create a module it will not be part of your theme. 
A theme is only for front-end changes, if you want to change functionality you need a module.

Comment: Yeah, so I would like not create module for this, as it is currently theme changes for now. But I want to know an easy way for it. I am new to magento, may be there should be an easy way of customizing html.

Comment: Well that depends on what you want to customize. Some functionality is configurable from the magento backend, but it's limited.

I can also recommend [this](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-mega-menu-extension.html) extension.

Comment: It is simple customization like my menu is in bootstrap, so I want to follow that structure, which seems not achievable in topmenu.phtml file

Comment: It's not, the only way you can change this structure is from this method, where it's generated.

In this file:
`/vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php`

Method:
`_getHtml` 

The method generates the HTML you are looking to change.

I would recommend [overriding](https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Overriding-a-block-in-Magento-2/td-p/6831) it, which would require a module.